# Getting data from table ?

Tags: perl

how to display data (Stock name, Capitals, Close Price, Market value)from the website in terminal? I have this website:

http://www.tpex.org.tw/web/stock/aftertrading/daily_mktval/mkt.php?l=en-us

, I create somethink.

```
    my $url = 'http://www.tpex.org.tw/web/stock/aftertrading/daily_mktval/mkt.php?l=en-us';


  use LWP::Simple;
  my $content = get $url;
  die "Couldn't get $url" unless defined $content;
```

But I don't really know how to use `$content` to print the data which I need.

I'll be grateful for each help :)

Comment: what about to download this link http://www.tpex.org.tw/web/stock/aftertrading/daily_mktval/mkt_print.php?l=en-us&d=2016/06/04&s=0,asc,0

Comment: But how to do it? Using $content ?

Comment: You must describe and give an example of the output that you need before anyone can help you

Comment: @Borodin 
Output should be like that:
OBI Pharma, Inc.  171,199,584  594.00  101,692
Vanguard  Co.  1,638,982,267  53.90  88,341
and more rows.  Just simple display

Comment: This doesn't seem to be too hard. What is the problem that you're having? What have you written that doesn't work?

Comment: Please edit your question to add more information, not the comments.

Comment: @mkHun could you tell me how you get this link to this table?

Comment: @Ice Simply click the  'Print/Export HTML' button on top of the table.

Comment: @Ice: Please don't just delete your questions before we have had a chance to understand your issues

Comment: @Borodin that was bad question, my bad. Sorry :(

Comment: @Ice: Maybe. We will never know now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to take a look at the excellent [`HTML::TableExtract` module](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::TableExtract)

Here's an example that uses the module to extract the data you require. I've used the URL for the printer-friendly version of the page for two reasons: the standard page uses JavaScript to build the table after it has been downloaded, so it isn't available to `LWP::Simple` which doesn't have JavaScript support; and it includes all the information on a single page, whereas the main page splits it up into many short sections

This is a far more robust, clear, and flexible technique than using regex patterns to parse HTML, which is generally a terrible idea

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use LWP::Simple;
use HTML::TableExtract;

use open qw/ :std :encoding(utf-8) /;

use constant URL => 'http://www.tpex.org.tw/web/stock/aftertrading/daily_mktval/mkt_print.php?l=en-us';

my $content = get URL or die "Couldn't get " . URL;

my $te = HTML::TableExtract->new( headers => [
    qr/Stock\s+Name/,
    qr/Capitals/,
    qr/Close\s+Price/,
    qr/Market\s+Value/,
] );

$te->parse($content);

for my $row ( $te->rows ) {

    next unless $row->[0];        # Skip the final row with empty fields

    $_ = qq{"$_"} for $row->[0];  # Enclose the Stock Name in quotes
    tr/,//d for @{$row}[1,2,3];   # and remove commas from the numeric columns

    print join(',', @$row), "\n";
}
```

#### output

```
"OBI Pharma, Inc.",171199584,594.00,101692
"Vanguard International Semiconductor Co.",1638982267,53.90,88341
"Hermes Microvision, Inc.",71000000,1155.00,82005
"TaiMed Biologics Inc.",247732750,238.00,58960
"Phison Electronics Corp.",197373993,271.00,53488
"FamilyMart.co.,Ltd",223220000,202.00,45090
"WIN SEMICONDUCTORS CORP.",596666262,65.30,38962
"PChome online Inc.",99854871,368.50,36796
"TUNG THIH ELECTRONIC CO.,LTD.",84488699,435.00,36752
"ST.SHINE OPTICAL CO.,LTD",50416516,694.00,34989
"POYA CO.,LTD",95277388,350.00,33347
"SIMPLO TECHNOLOGY CO.,LTD.",308284198,108.00,33294
"LandMark Optoelectronics Corporation",69909752,474.50,33172
"Ginko International Co., Ltd.",92697472,340.00,31517
"GIGASOLAR MATERIALS CORPORATION",60989036,506.00,30860
"TTY Biopharm Company Limited",248649959,114.00,28346
"CHIPBOND TECHNOLOGY CORPORATION",649261998,41.90,27204
"Globalwafers.Co.,Ltd.",369250000,69.10,25515
"eMemory Technology lnc.",75782242,321.00,24326
"Parade Technology, Ltd.",76111677,315.50,24013
"PharmaEngine, Inc.",102101000,235.00,23993
"JIH SUN FINANCIAL HOLDING CO., LTD",3396302860,6.86,23298
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple pattern matching and some trick enough for to do it.

In your task `$content` contain the whole text.

First, extract the table body content from the `$content` by using `.+` with `s` flag. `s` flag helps to allow, match the any character with new line.

Second, split the extracted data by using `</tr>`.

Third, Iterate the foreach for the array then again will do pattern matching with grouping for extract the data.

Here `$l1` and `$l2` stores the `rank` and `stock code`. And the other data will be stored into the `@arc` variable

```
my $url = 'http://www.tpex.org.tw/web/stock/aftertrading/daily_mktval/mkt_print.php?l=en-us&d=2016/06/04&s=0,asc,0';
use LWP::Simple;
my $content = get $url;
die "Couldn't get $url" unless defined $content;


my ($table_body) = $content =~m/<tbody>(.+)<\/tbody>/s;

my @ar = split("</tr>",$table_body);

foreach my $lines(@ar)
{
    my ($l1,$l2,@arc) = $lines =~m/>(.+?)<\/td>/g;
    $, = "\t\t";
    print @arc,"\n";
}
```

Comment: What $, = "\t,\t" doing ?

Comment: @Ice This is nothing this is called [output field separator](http://perlmaven.com/output-field-separator-and-list-separator). I just add the two tabs in  your output.